# Meshlab: Transforming Vertex Colour into Texture won't work: "path not allowed"

Tags: texture-mapping, meshlab

I'm quite new to Meshlab, and unsurprisingly ran into a few obstacles. Anyhow, I have been looking for a solution online but didn't find one.
I have a very large .ply-file containing a mesh that I made in CloudCompare from a 3D-scan of a rock art cave and I want to transform the vertex colour into a texture.
However, when I am trying to use the "*Texture: Vertex Color to Texture*"-Filter, type in the path that I want my texture to be saved at, and hit "apply", it displays an error message saying
**"path in texture file not allowed".**
I imagine this refers to the path I tried to save my texture at, neither name nor path contain a space, i've tried working around it somehow by saving it elsewhere but didn't manage to get it to work.
Also, i was going to reduce vertices count afterwards, but I need to extract a rather high res texture first.
Anyone ever encountered this or has an idea as to why this might happen?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this problem？

Answer (score 1):

type in any word into that box and DONT type in a path.

Example: my path in that box was F:\Personal\3D_scans\textures\tree.png

After literally 2 hours i got exhausted and deleted it and wrote: "ffffffffffffff"

It worked, and i realised it's looking for a name of the texture you want to give

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today, I managed to solve the issue by checking "run in compatibility mode" with windows 8 (I am on windows 10). Maybe that will help!